# iOS Simulator for apps

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I would like to run app store apps on my Xcode iOS Simulator. When I try to access the App Store in Safari the simulator shows a message. "Cannot Open Page" Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.
Is there a way of downloading apps from the App Store to the iOS Simulator?

Comment: No way to do it on Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not yet possible to do that

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone Simulator is for Intel ia32/x86 CPU's. ARM code won't run on it. XCode compiles completely different object code for the Simulator and for the device. Only the device code for ARM CPU's is uploaded to the App Store. So technically its not possible.

Comment: And additionally it's against apple philosophy either way, so they won't be changing this anytime soon (=ever)